# Have Java Streams GroupingBy result Map include a key for each value of an enum, even if value is an empty List

Tags: java, enums, java-stream

This question is about Java Streams' groupingBy capability.

Suppose I have a class, `WorldCup`:

```
public class WorldCup {

    int year;
    Country champion;

    // all-arg constructor, getter/setters, etc
}
```

and an enum, `Country`:

```
public enum Country {
    Brazil, France, USA
}
```

and the following code snippet:

```
WorldCup wc94 = new WorldCup(1994, Country.Brazil);
WorldCup wc98 = new WorldCup(1998, Country.France);

List<WorldCup> wcList = new ArrayList<WorldCup>();
wcList.add(wc94);
wcList.add(wc98);

Map<Country, List<Integer>> championsMap = wcList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorldCup::getCountry, Collectors.mapping(WorldCup::getYear));
```

After running this code, `championsMap` will contain:

```
Brazil: [1994]
France: [1998]
```

Is there a succinct way to have this list include an entry for all of the values of the enum?  What I'm looking for is:

```
Brazil: [1994]
France: [1998]
USA: []
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches you can take.

The map which would be used for accumulating the stream data can be prepopulated with entries corresponding to every *enum-member*. To access all existing *enum-members* you can use `values()` method or [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)).

It can be achieved using *three-args* version of [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) or through a custom collector created via `Collector.of()`.

```
Map<Country, List<Integer>> championsMap = wcList.stream()
    .collect(
        () -> EnumSet.allOf(Country.class).stream()         // supplier
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                c -> new ArrayList<>()
            )),
        (Map<Country, List<Integer>> map, WorldCup next) -> // accumulator
            map.get(next.getCountry()).add(next.getYear()),
        (left, right) ->                                    // combiner
            right.forEach((k, v) -> left.get(k).addAll(v))
    );
```

Another option is to add missing entries to the map after reduction of the stream has been finished.

For that we can use built-in *collector* [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)).

```
Map<Country, List<Integer>> championsMap = wcList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(WorldCup::getCountry,
            Collectors.mapping(WorldCup::getYear,
                Collectors.toList())),
        map -> {
            EnumSet.allOf(Country.class)
                .forEach(country -> map.computeIfAbsent(country, k -> new ArrayList<>())); // if you're not going to mutate these lists - use Collections.emptyList()
            return map;
        }
    ));
```